# SSH tunnel between 3 box to get internet access

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, routing, ssh-tunneling

The network looks like this : Server X -- My machine -- Server Y

My machine has SSH access to both boxes. Server Y has internet but not server X.
How can I make a tunnel so server X can acces the internet through Y?

Thank you

Comment: Do we have to use a two-step tunnel or can we do things like enabling routing on your computer?

Comment: Two-steps tunnel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this but none of them are good solutions.  The way I would probably do it if I had to is like this:

1. From your machine, tunnel port 222 from your machine to port 22 server Y

   `ssh -L222:localhost:22 servery`
2. From server X, create a dynamic tunnel from server X to server Y using the previously constructed tunnel. Note: your destination on this command is `mymachine` but the credentials you'll use are for server Y since it's what you're actually connecting to.

   `ssh -D8080 -p 222 mymachine`
3. Setup server X with a system wide SOCKS Proxy of `localhost:8080`

Comment: How the second command would create a tunnel between X & Y? you're only giving it port 222 which has been forwareded on my machine to port 22 on Y. There is no reference to server X

Comment: I just edited my answer. The command on step #2 should be run from server X.